# How to get zone from the instance id/name using GCP apis?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine

I am looking for zone for an instance. I have instance details like id and name. Is there an api for the same in GCP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally Compute Engine service methods require the Project and Zone to enumerate instances **but** if you use the following `gcloud` command to describe an instance **without** specifying a zone:

```bash
gcloud compute instances describe ${INSTANCE} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--log-http
```

You'll discover that it uses:

```
GET /compute/v1/projects/{PROJECT}/aggregated/instances
```

This is documented by [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) as [`instances.aggregated`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/aggregatedList).

`gcloud compute instances describe` (without a zone) then uses [`instances.get`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/get) to get details of the instance.

It's a more expensive method because it enumerates instances for every zone but, it permits you to find instances without having the zone.

You can simplify `gcloud`'s approach by using the equivalent of:

```bash
gcloud compute instances list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--filter=name=${INSTANCE}
```

Which is:

```
GET compute/v1/projects/ackal-221102/aggregated/instances?filter=name%3D${INSTANCE}
```

As almost always, using Google's [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/libraries) is the strongly-preferred way of coding use of this service.

Comment: Thanks. I am currently working with AggregatedList using GET /compute/v1/projects/{PROJECT}/aggregated/instances. Using api filters I could filter the results for the instance id or any other key and extracting the zone programmatically.